# DIY Database / Web App Platforms

Tags: database, development-environment, saas

I am looking at platforms like Caspio, Zoho and Kohezion as a way to fast-teck creation of a web-based inventory management tool to support an e-commerce site.  I am interested in having more power/features than having things overly simplified for non-tech users, but I want to stop short of doing the back-end programming myself.  There seem to be so many options.  Anyone have experience in this area or a recommendation on how to narrow down my search to the best platforms?

Comment: I would suggest that this isn't a programming related question. Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question won't do well on webapps @Jordan... Tool recommendations are off-topic throughout SE. It's best not to send someone to another site unless you're highly active on that site, 'cause it's a bit crap as a user to have multiple questions shot down.

Answer (score 0):

Try Bitrix24, it has pretty good CRM with product catalog, it's free and can be easily integrated with your website.

Comment: Thanks Phillip.  Will check it out.